# Getting with Jquery src from a css class

Tags: jquery, css, class

I'm using the UberGallery and I don't know to get the "src" from the class "cboxPhoto":

```
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 500px; overflow: auto; height: 333px;"><img class="cboxPhoto" src="test.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 500px; height: 333px; float: none;"></div>
```

I'm trying but it doesnt't works.

```
var x = $('cboxPhoto').attr('src');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `.` to select a class: `$('.cboxPhoto')`

Comment: Thx, but the result is always "undefined" with alert(x)

Comment: Are you sure that code is executed after the document is loaded? Make sure the script is just before the closing `</body>` tag, or use the `ready` event.

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/eecqtz9q/2/

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the `cboxPhoto` class? This will select the first one. You might need to use a more specific selector to get the one you want.

Comment: The code is before the closing <head> tag and i'm using it at colorboxScripts.php  (https://jsfiddle.net/wtkkg8j9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated with your Fiddle** (removed php)

- Use dot to reference a class selector `$('.cboxPhoto')`
- Make sure you are loading jQuery.
- Added `alert(x)` for demo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    //var ficken = $(this).attr('href');
    var x = $('.cboxPhoto').attr('src');
    alert(x);
  });
});
```

```css
#cboxLoadedContent {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 333px;
}

.cboxPhoto {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 500px;
  height: 333px;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">click me</a>
<div id="cboxLoadedContent">
  <img class="cboxPhoto" src="test.jpg">
</div>
```